# typescript: how to make a type depend on a field value

Tags: typescript

I have a structure like the following, and I want details to be a CardType when method_type equals 'card', and to be a SepaDetail when it's sepa.

How can I have typescript enforce this?

```js
type PaymentMethod = {
  id: string,
  provider: Provider,
  holder_name: string,
  [more fields...],
  method_type: "card" | "sepa",
  details: CardDetails | SepaDetails
}

type CardDetails = {
  brand: string,
  last_digits: string
}

type SepaDetails = {
  last_digits?: string
}
```

see this [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiAthAdsAshYALA9gEygF4oBvAKCigEt8AuKAZ2ACdqUBzAGkqmRwIB9UJAYAiAMZwW%20MVAA%20UMYwhg4YnlXxY41ADaMGAYWn4AIjv2MFUAMqq4F4LoPkAvuXIjoJmU5fWJBRUAEYscCj0TKzs3Lx6cMyC%20NQc1MCG0Wyc7p7edg7%20VsRk8YnAyanpjAD8DMzZHO5AA)

Comment: Here is a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiAthAdsAshYALA9gEygF4oBvAKCigEt8AuKAZ2ACdqUBzAGkqmRwIB9UJAYAiAMZwW+Mb3xY41ADaMGAYWn4AIopWNyAXygAfMpVoNmbTjyr88+YeAjjGEMHDlUFwJaoYAZQ84XT99KCNychFoTRkw-0ZicyoAIxY4FHomVnZuXmU4ZkF8ag5qYDVcmw4omJcoYM9EiJIKKiKSsoqqgH4rPM56iVwUZigwRAZ4JFQMLEcUjqhfJLoVzuLgUvLKtTEARgAmAGZvKEM7GnojsWuHIVi6MXdPOUMgA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a union of object types:

```
type PaymentMethod = {
  id: string,
  method_type: 'card',
  details: CardDetails,
} | {
  id: string,
  method_type: 'sepa',
  details: SepaDetails
}
```

If you have a lot of fields in common that you don't want to repeat, then you can either use an interface that you extend:

```
interface BasePaymentMethod {
  id: string,
  [more fields...],
  method_type: 'card' | 'sepa'
}

interface CardPaymentMethod extends BasePaymentMethod {
  method_type: 'card',
  details: CardDetails,
}

interface SepaPaymentMethod extends BasePaymentMethod {
  method_Type: 'sepa'
  details: SepaDetails
}

type PaymentMethod = CardPaymentMethod | SepaPaymentMethod
```

Or if you prefer types instead of interfaces, you can do intersections (`&`):

```
type BasePaymentMethod = {
  id: string,
  [more fields...],
  method_type: 'card' | 'sepa'
}

type CardPaymentMethod = BasePaymentMethod & {
  method_type: 'card',
  details: CardDetails,
}

type SepaPaymentMethod = BasePaymentMethod & {
  method_Type: 'sepa'
  details: SepaDetails
}

type PaymentMethod = CardPaymentMethod | SepaPaymentMethod
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. There are a bunch of other fields that I don't want to repeat. I've just updated the question

Comment: Added examples for what to do if you have a bunch of fields you don't want to repeat.

Comment: I added another option that's pretty similar to your second approach

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way:

```js
type PaymentMethod = {
  id: string,
  [bunch of other fields...],
} & (CardDetails | SepaDetails)

type CardDetails = {
  method_type: "card",
  details: {
    brand: string,
    last_digits: string
  }
}

type SepaDetails = {
  method_type: "sepa",
  details: {
    last_digits?: string
  }
}

const pm1: PaymentMethod = {
  id: '1',
  method_type: 'card',
  details: {
    brand: 'zz',
    last_digits: 'xxx'
  }
}

const pm2: PaymentMethod = {
  id: '1',
  method_type: 'sepa',
  details: {
    last_digits: 'xxx'
  }
}
```

see [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiAthAdsAshYALA9gEygF4oBvAKCigEt8AuKAZ2ACdqUBzAGnIF8oAZFAAUAYTgt8AESxxqAG0ZQAPlADKEMHBnA5igJTlyoSFHGSdepSQpVkOAgH0TEBgCIAxhPxueVfLIKjAy2VFAARixwKPRMrOzclGHycMyO%20NQc1MDBcWycSbx8Ri7qmtqBisRkSfZ4%20M7grlBujOW%20SQG6QSFJVClpGVk5APwMzPkchcXkHrgozFBgiACMDPBIqBhY9dWhtAwA5CuHflB1Ti5HXpKnnZW5oVSR0bGHAF7vd2FQA8DpmWyuUOAA8wYdpkVZvNFssAEzrBDINCYByEGxJA5QY7fc47S5NI5tLS4rpWXo-P4A4bAsEgiFUIq8IA)